# Forcing work directory when executing jar file in systemd

Tags: java, linux, daemon, init, systemd

I am attempting to start a jar from a systemd service, in linux. The jar that I am executing assumes that within the current directory, there is an xml file. I am passing the name of that file, with the -config argument. The sample service I have created is below:

`[Unit]
Description=my service
After=network.target`

`[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="xml_file_name=sample.xml"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/jar/myapp.jar -config ${xml_file_name}`

The service file above is placed in the /usr/lib/systemd/system directory, and is called myservice.service. I am doing the following commands to start it:

`systemctl daemon-reload
 systemctl stop myservice.service
 systemctl start myservice.service
 systemctl status myservice.service`

The `systemctl status myservice.service` command shows that the jar file ran, but my application says that it cannot find ${xml_file_name}.

In addition, my jar states that it was executed from the / directory. I believe that this is part of the problem, because the ${xml_file_name} is only applicable in the /path/to/jar/ directory.

Things tried:

- `-Xbootclasspath/p:"/path/to/jar/"`: prepend the path of the jars
  location, so that maybe the ${xml_file_name} can be seen.
- changed the /path/to/jar/ to make sure it has all possible permissions enabled
- I tried to add `User=root` under the `[Service]` section of my systemd service, but it made no change. Either way, only root user is on the machine, and the permissions all seem to check out.

What makes this even more strange is that if I cd to / , and then manually execute:

`/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/jar/myapp.jar -config sample.xml`

everything words just fine.

Is there something evident that I am missing here? Is it possible to tell systemd service, execute this java jar, but make sure that the working path is `/path/to/jar/` as opposed to `/` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up using the following attribute under the `[Service]` section:

`[Service]
...
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/jar
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar my.jar -config sample.xml`

Solved the problem!

Answer (score -2):

Try following:

```
 cd /path/to/jar && /usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/jar/myapp.jar -config sample.xml
```

If you use && in Linux like systems, it combines the two commands in the way the second will be executed only after the first will be executed successfully. So basically it would first change the working directory and then run the java jar command from the changed directory, which could have solved the problem.