# Systemd force directory of execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, systemd

I have a Java app and I want to create a system service to execute that jar at boot. I know how to do it for **upstart** and **SysV** but I'm having troubles with **systemd**.

The difficult part is that I need that the jar be executed from within the directory where it resides, so that it pick up `application.properties` next to  it, and also some directories that are relative to the jar location.

For example, assume the following structure:

```
+-var
   +-myapp
       +-app.jar
       +-app.log
       +-application.properties
       +-certificate.jks
       +-images
           +-img1.jpg
```

The way I want to execute the jar is:

```
$ cd /var/myapp
$ java -jar app.jar
```

So as I'm in the **myapp** directory when executing the jar, it logs to `app.log`, it pick up `application.properties` and reads the `certificate.jks`. Also it could find the directory `images`.

I've try this as unit file for **systemd**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=App Description
 After=network.target

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 User=sebasira
 WorkingDirectory=/var/myapp
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar app.jar
 SuccessExitStatus=143
 Restart=on-failure

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It runs the jar file, but not from within `/var/myapp`

How can I solve it?

Comment: It's somehow like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161656/forcing-work-directory-when-executing-jar-file-in-systemd but that is not working for me

Comment: Did you try my simple (maybe naive) solution below? It used to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a shell script like in /var/myapp:

```
#!/bin/sh
# runMyJar.sh    
java  -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /var/myapp/app.jar
```

Make it executable of course.

Then configure it as service to fork at boot:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=My App Jar

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    ExecStart=/var/myapp/runMyJar.sh

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Add other systemd options as you wish.

The jar file should execute with /var/myapp as default home or workspace directory.

---

**EDIT** (based on @sebasira comment)

The following `.sh` script may also work with this systemd configuration:

```
#!/bin/sh
# runMyJar.sh    
cd /var/myapp/;java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Sorry I have not try it yet, give a couple of hours

Comment: Thank you! I manage to make it work with your guidance. I just change the script from **runMyJar.sh** to `cd /var/myapp/;java -jar app.jar`